# angular UI popup content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular UI and I am using a popup (popover) as a complex menu. But I could not find a way to insert html content like buttons, texts, images into the popover. Here is my html code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
    <link href="//https:netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>


    <br><br><br><br>

<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <button popover-placement="bottom" Popover-animation="true" popover="I have a title!" popover-title="The title." class="btn btn-default">Click me</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the example.js has the following code which I found a little bit confusing.

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    content: 'Hello, World!',
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Title'
  };
});
```

Please let me know how to add html contents and also describe the js function used.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use pop-over is popover-template directive.

```
<script id="myPopoverTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template">
//Insert detail here
    <div><button>Test</button></div>
    <hr />
</script>
```

And the html go like this :

```
<button popover-placement="bottom" Popover-animation="true" popover="I have a title!" popover-title="The title." popover-template="myPopoverTemplate.html" class="btn btn-default">Click me</button>
```

This is my first time answer, Sorry for struggle.
PS. Im not sure too, i didn't go on test run.